# Python - parsing HTML from HTTPS url using lxml - urllib2.urlopen workaround will not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, lxml, urllib2

I have a previously-working web scraper. However, the website which it is specifically designed to scrape from has recently changed to using HTTPS, making the relevant code excerpt below no longer work.

```
    from lxml import html

    url = 'http://www.blahblah.com'
    good_data = False
    while good_data ==False:
        try:
            data = html.fromstring(html.tostring(html.parse(url)))
            good_data=True
        except Exception:
            good_data=False
            print 'scraping failed'
            winsound.Beep(800,1000)
            time.sleep(pause)
```

Where previously the data would be successfully parsed into 'data', I now get an IOError from lxml.

I did some reading - here in particular: [error with parse function in lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116269/error-with-parse-function-in-lxml) - and I attempted to implement the given solution using urllib2 as follows:

```
    from lxml import html
    from urllib import urlopen

    url = 'http://www.blahblah.com'
    good_data = False
    while good_data ==False:
        try:
            data = html.fromstring(html.tostring(html.parse(urlopen(url))))
            good_data=True
        except Exception:
            good_data=False
            print 'scraping failed'
            winsound.Beep(800,1000)
            time.sleep(pause)
```

but now I get back the error

```
"TypeError: expected string or buffer".
```

This happens whether I scrape from http or https://www.blahblah.com.

Either a fix for the original issue or a fix for the fix for the original issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `requests`?

Comment: Just tried just now. Did r = requests.get(url) - which I believe is correct. It doesn't throw me any errors, but doesn't actually seem to give me anything, i.e r.text, r._content are both empty

Comment: Got it - had to spoof the Chrome user agent as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491872/python-request-geturl-returns-empty-content to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use requests library to get html data and use BeautifulSoup to extract data from html retrieved pages.

You requests library to get data from sites, this data will be in HTML

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.google.com/search'
my_headers = { 'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/11.0' }
payload = { 'q' : 'pizza', 'start' : '0' }
r = requests.get( url, params = payload, headers = my_headers )
```

You can use BeautifulSoup library to extract any type of information from retrieved data (HTML data)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup( r.text, 'html.parser' )
```

Now if you want text data you can use this function

```
soup.getText()
```

If you want title or anyother tag information you can use , like in given example I've retrieved all H3 tags

```
h3tags = soup.find_all( 'h3', class_='r' )
```