# I need to create a new string, with the contents being the title of a website

Tags: python, web

I though something like (1) would work, but it throws an error. Any ideas or tips?

(1)

```
versionPreCheck = lxml.html.parse("URL")
versionCheck = versionPreCheck.find(".//title").text

LatestVersion = (versionCheck.read())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 132, in <module>
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3426, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1839, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1865, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1769, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1162, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 600, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 710, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 637, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
OSError: Error reading file 'bazorkversion--grify.repl.co': failed to load external entity "bazorkversion--grify.repl.co"
```

And here is the title:

https://bazorkversion--grify.repl.co/
the title is string "PreAlpha 3"
(It appears in the top of your browser's tabs, next to the site's favicon)

Comment: What do you mean by "title"? Title of the URL? Is there a tag called title? Perhaps supply a valid URL as an example

Comment: Added my error to the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You aren't the only one receiving this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116269/error-with-parse-function-in-lxml), and it could be a fault in `lxml`.

Instead, perhaps try and use another web-scraping module like `BeautifulSoup`, as well as the `requests` module to receive a request from the URL:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> r = requests.get('https://bazorkversion--grify.repl.co/')
>>> soup = BS(r.text, 'lxml')
>>> soup.title.text
'PreAlpha 3'
```