# Reading and writing non-English characters from websites with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, wikipedia

I'm doing a bit of data scraping on Wikipedia, and I want to read certain entries.
I'm using the `urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.com')` and `urllib.read()`

This works fine until it encounters non English characters like [Stanislav Šesták](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanislav_%C5%A0est%C3%A1k)
Here's are the first few lines:

```
import urllib

print urllib.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanislav_Šesták").read()
```

result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-nojs">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" /><title>Stanislav ֵ estֳ¡k - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</title>
<meta name="generator" content="MediaWiki 1.23wmf8" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/x-wiki" title="Edit this page" href="/w/index.php?title=Stanislav_%C5%A0est%C3%A1k&amp;action=edit" />
<link rel="edit" title="Edit this page" href="/w/index.php?title=Stanislav_%C5%A0est%C3%A1k&amp;action=edit" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="//bits.wikimedia.org/apple-touch/wikipedia.png" />
```

How can I retain the non-English characters?
In the end this code will write the entry title and the URL in a .txt file.

Comment: Lines of what? Post a fully-functional script that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Lines of the Wiki entry as read by Python.

Comment: The character encoding is UTF-8, as indicated by the meta tag (and corroborated by experience). You are viewing or saving it in some other encoding. You are not showing us this step, and I don't think we can guess what it is.

Comment: What are the actual bytes in the title? The first accented character should be 0xC5 0xA0 and the second ought to be 0xC3 0xA1, as you can see from the URL.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you're asking me. When I view the source code on the Wiki entry, it says UTF-8, all my script does is print that, what step is there supposed to be in the way?

Comment: Then you are probably viewing it in something which isn't properly configured for UTF-8. Again, what are the actual bytes where you see the wrong glyphs?

Comment: This is what I see:http://oi41.tinypic.com/fxs288.jpg The first is U+05Bx5, the second is U+05Bx3, both Hebrew diacritic marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- non-ascii characters in a string literal: you must specify encoding declaration at the top of the module in this case
- you should urlencode the url path (`u"Stanislav_Šesták"` -> `"Stanislav_%C5%A0est%C3%A1k"`)
- you are printing bytes received from a web to your terminal. Unless both use the same character encoding then you might see garbage instead of some characters
- to interpret html, you should probably use an html parser

Here's a code example that takes into account the above remarks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cgi
import urllib
import urllib2

wiki_title = u"Stanislav_Šesták"
url_path = urllib.quote(wiki_title.encode('utf-8'))
r = urllib2.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + url_path)
_, params = cgi.parse_header(r.headers.get('Content-Type', ''))
encoding = params.get('charset')
content = r.read()
unicode_text = content.decode(encoding or 'utf-8')
print unicode_text # if it fails; set PYTHONIOENCODING
```

Related:

- [urllib2 read to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1020892/4279)
- [How can I retrieve the page title of a webpage using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51233/4279)