# HTML Specific <h1> Text in Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, html-parsing

I want to get only title of the [page](https://www.strawpoll.me/20321563/r) `<h1>This is Title</h1>` in python.

I tried some method but couldn't get desired result.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get("https://www.strawpoll.me/20321563/r")

html_content = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

for i in soup.get_text("p", {"class": "result-list"}):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use lxml for such tasks. You could use beautifulsoup as well.

```
import lxml.html
t = lxml.html.parse(url)
print t.find(".//title").text
```

(This is from [How can I retrieve the page title of a webpage using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233/how-can-i-retrieve-the-page-title-of-a-webpage-using-python) by Peter Hoffmann)

Answer (score 1):

You could use BeautifulSoup as see:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = "html as text(Source)"

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

p = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'titleClass'})
p.a.extract()
print p.text.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

I add given code to mine.

```
title = soup.title
print(title.string[:-24:])  # Last 24 character of title is always constant.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method if you are still couldn't get the result that you want.

```
import urllib
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.strawpoll.me/20321563/r'
uCLient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uCLient.read()
uCLient.close()    
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
_div = page_soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='div' and tag.has_attr('id') and 
tag['id']=="result-list") 
title = _div.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name=='h1')

print(title)
```

Output : `[<h1>This is Title</h1>]`

Comment: Actually I only need "This is Title"